# pgRouting - How get all pubs that are less than x meters from a point

Tags: pgrouting, osm2po

I'm building a Mobile App to discover all pubs that are less than 2 km away from my position!

- First I obtained all the roads of a town using Open Street Maps "osm2po"
- Next I obtained all coordinates of the pubs using Qgis (Desktop app)

Now, I need to find all pubs that are less than 2km away from my position.

How can I do this with pgrouting?

Comment: You should provide some more information on what code you have already tried, how it failed and other relevant information like version of PostGIS and pgrouting. 
PostGIS has the function `ST_DWithIn` which can help to find all geometries which are within a specific distance of each other. You only need pgrouting if you want to calculate distances within a network.

Comment: Yes. you have reason. I need PostGIS to get all pubs that are less than x km of the my coordinates.
You have some one example to this ?

Comment: Confirm that you are interested in the shortest distance between the points even if you should drive much longer by car because you can't go through the parks and buildings.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ST_DWithin` as a filter on your location as below

```
SELECT pubs.name 
FROM pubs 
WHERE ST_DWithin([Your Location in units of projection], 
pubs.the_geom, [Distance in units of the projection used]);
```

`the_geom` is the geometry column of your pubs table.
If your location data is in GeoJSON format (You could maybe clarify this in your question) you could use this as input like below:

```
SELECT pubs.name 
    FROM pubs 
    WHERE ST_DWithin(
      SELECT 
      ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[711330.0, 6197924.9]}')
      ,pubs.the_geom, 2000)
```

The above solution assumes that both pub data and your own location data is in the same projection and that the units of measurement is meters.

I would recommend that you read the documentation for `ST_DWithin`
[here](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

Comment: In the second query, postgresql give me a error :

<code>
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Select"
LINE 3:     WHERE ST_DWithin( Select ST_AsText(

<code>

i need to install something extension?

Comment: Hmm. The st_astext function was an error try without it

Comment: i did so:

<code>
SELECT name ,st_asgeojson(geom)
FROM pubs as p 
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-8.1235 40.3521)',4326),3857), 
   ST_Transform(p.geom, 3857),
   2000);

</code>

and work perfectly

Comment: That's great! Consider accepting my answer, so that I'll get a reputation bonus or alternatively provide your own answer and accept that. Regards